Where can I find the schematic and CAD files of an open source PCB?
This is a fairly well known power bank fast charging module which is open source. I am unable to find its PCB CAD files on the internet. Can somebody provide it? Even just the schematic would help.

Where did you get the information that the design is open source? Perhaps whoever told you that can also guide you to the design materials.

Also, what is a "CADZ" file? If its a file from some specific CAD tool, how do you know that this board is designed using that tool?

What makes you think it is open source? If it were the schematics would be easily available.

@The Photon sorry that was typo. Actually nobody said it is open source, I have seen atleast 10 companies (some of them are chinese)  making the same board. Exact same board. So i thought may be it is open source

If you know what the main chip is in the design, you'll likely find these boards follow the recommended circuit in the data sheet very closely.

I have seen atleast 10 companies (some of them are chinese) making the same board. Exact same board. So i thought may be it is open source... Or it's just entirely possible that whomever made this has sold their design, i.e. an OEM.


I have seen atleast 10 companies (some of them are chinese) making the same board. Exact same board. So i thought may be it is open source

Unfortunately this is unlikely - the part is listed as "Generic 5 USB Port PowerBank"... You'll probably find that it's a whitelabel module sold as-is to a number of vendors, and then appearing under multiple brand names. It's also possible that there is some amount of "cloning" going on, but it's difficult to say from the single source you've given.
You'll find many products available like this - in some cases they are made cheaper by omitting certain components (ESD protection for example) or substituting in cheaper alternatives.
I'd suggest that, in general, it's advisable to stay away from such products if you want a reliable and reproducible design.

I am looking for a reliable power bank circuit which I will design my own. Can you provide any such circuit shematic? It's specification should be same as the product given in the link
